# Function for menu open close does not work

Tags: javascript, html, menu

I have a menu with a script that should be closed when the page is opened, but the menu script is giving an error and my functions don't work.

Give this error on the console: *Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access '_this' before initialization*

And I can't understand the error and how to solve it.

Error:
[image: 1]

My Coding HTML:

**Why are you giving an error?**

```js
function removeClassBody() {
  var body = document.querySelector('body');
  body.classList.remove('no-js'); //REMOVENDO a classe "no-js" do body
  body.classList.add('js'); // ADICIONANDO a classe "js" no body    
}

removeClassBody();



function menuConfig() {
  var menu = new Menu({
    container: '.header__nav',
    toggleBtn: '.header__btnMenu',
    widthEnable: 1024
  });

}

menuConfig();

function Menu(config) {
  this.nav = (typeof config.container === 'string') ?
    document.querySelector(config.container) : config.container

  this.btn = (typeof config.toggleBtn === 'string') ?
    document.querySelector(config.toggleBtn) : config.toggleBtn

  this.maxWidth = config.widthEnable || false;

  this.btn.removeAttribute('style');
  fechaMenu();

  let _aberto = false;
  let _this = this;

  this.btn.addEventListener('click', abertoOuFechado);

  function abertoOuFechado() {
    if (!_aberto) {
      abreMenu();
    } else {
      fechaMenu();
    }
  }

  function abreMenu() {

    let _top = _this.nav.getBoundingClientRect().top + 'px'

    let _style = {
      maxHeight: 'calc(100vh -' + _top + ' )',
      overflow: 'hidden'
    }

    aplicandoStyleNaNav(_style);

    _aberto = true;

  }

  function aplicandoStyleNaNav(_style) {

    Object.keys(_style).forEach(stl => {
      _this.nav.style[stl] = _style[stl]
    })
  }

  function fechaMenu() {
    let _style = {
      maxHeight: '0px',
      overflow: 'hidden'
    }

    aplicandoStyleNaNav(_style);

    _aberto = false;
  }

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <title> Infusion </title>
</head>

<body class="no-js">

  <header class="header">
    <a href="index.html" class="logo-text">Infusion</a>

    <button style="display: none;" class="header__btnMenu">
                <i class="fas fa-bars fa-2x"></i><span class="sr-only">Menu</span></button>

    <nav class="header__nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">design folio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">services</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/menu.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: _this is not a global var so `Object.keys(_style).forEach(stl => { _this.nav.style[stl] = _style[stl]  })` will give that error -  you need to read up on what `this` means and not use _this all over the place in random fashion

Comment: In the `Menu` function body you invoke `fechaMenu` before initialising `_this` ;  `fechaMenu` then calls `aplicandoStyleNaNav` which tries to access `_this` and throw the error